# React router v4 - How to get current component in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way in react router to get the current component on the Switch?

```
const routes = {Home, ...}

<Layout>
  <Switch>
    {routes.map(r => <Route path={r.path} component={r.Component} />)} // I want to get this Component
  </Switch>
</Layout>

function Layout(props) {
   // I want to get the current component here
   return props.children
}
```

Comment: It would help to understand what underlying problem you are trying to solve.  The cheap answer is to just move your `Switch` to inside the `Layout` component because that solves the question you are asking.  But maybe you are trying to solve some deeper problem?

Comment: Yes @Brandon, I have a lot of routes, and I need to some particular component (like "Home") to modify the Layout component

Comment: Just add routes to the Layout component with render functions to render route-specific stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the element type by [React.Children APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

But I recommend use the Context API. The Context API is made for things like this.

[Context API: `Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `props.match` to get the current active route. React-router provides this.

Many articles explain how to use it, here is one: https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/